# Change headers to yellow in SQL (inside the query)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a query that is just some selects with joins.

I wanted to ask if that is possible to change headers to yellow in SQL code?

```
SELECT a.cccn, f.dm
    (SELECT 
         
         COUNT([LOC]),
         SUM([OH]) 
     FROM 
         smmm
```

Comment: SQL is not concerned about presentation, that's the job of your reporting tool/application.

Comment: SSMS settings do allow for some general background color customizations, but there isn't a setting that targets the column header background color.  The [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/menu-help/options-environment-fonts-and-colors-page?view=sql-server-ver15) apply to the entire background color of the results panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible because colors are not a part of what SQL Server returns.

SQL Server returns DATA - ONLY.

SSMS is not a front end tool, it is purely an administrator's toolbox.

So, it also does not offer this function.

Answer (score -1):

If i got it right you want to change the headers in the query result set for further copying, for example, to an Excel spreadsheet, then you should use aliases like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20   
     a.demand_chain As [Demand Chain], item As [DMDUnit], descr As [Descr], hist_type As [Hist type], 
     fcst_cnt As [Current 111 DFU Count], loc_oh_cnt As [# Active Records (CKB)], ckb_cnt As [CKB Count], oh_total As [OH Qty]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         U_CHAINNAME AS Demand_Chain, 
         [ITEM],
         DMDUNIT.DESCR,
         COUNT(SKU.[LOC]) loc_oh_cnt,
         SUM([OH]) AS OH_Total
     FROM 
         [BYIntegration].[SCPOMGR].[SKU] SKU
```

Comment: Sorry, this IS an answer, just not for this question which asks explicitly about how to do it in SSMS.